# HP Pavilion System Restore program hangs on last step

Tags: windows-xp, hp-pavilion

My uncle has a HP Pavilion PC. We tried to restore from the RESTORE Partition, but after almost completing the procedure it hangs in the last step. The harddisk is making a lot of noise, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I already tried to reset the BIOS to factory settings, based on an HP knowlegde base article, but that doesn't seem to work.

I also can't get into the Safe mode of Windows XP; it says the Setup hasn't completed yet.

Please help.

Comment: I often do an XP system restore, but my Pavilion laptop has issues restarting.  I do a hard power down (4 seconds on power button), then power up, and if it starts properly, it says it has finished the restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reset the values in the BIOS of the computer, restarted the computer 
and completed the installation.